# How do I logged out from onedrive

Tags: android, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I am using [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android-auth) API to authenticate into Microsoft, but I don't know how to logged out using this API, please help me.

here is how I am authenticating

```
publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(getActivity(), AppConstants.OtherConstants.ONE_DRIVE_APP_ID);
 msalAuthenticationProvider = new MSALAuthenticationProvider(
                getActivity(),
                MyApplication.getInstance(),
                publicClientApplication,
                new String[]{
                        // An example set of scopes your application could use
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All",
                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite",
                        "offline_access",
                        "openid"
                });


        graphClient =
                GraphServiceClient
                        .builder()
                        .authenticationProvider(msalAuthenticationProvider)
                        .buildClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced my SDK with this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android